# What is the meaning of -e option in a shell test ('[') command?

Tags: shell, command

I'm working with shell command in Linux and I found this command:

```
while [ ! -e /tmp/.wm_ready ]; do sleep 0.1 ; done
```

I think this command does `sleep 0.1s` until `/tmp/.wm_ready` is created.

But I don't know what is `-e` option. Could anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, the `-e` option checks for both **file** and **directory** (symbolic links included).

The condition

```
[ ! -e /tmp/.wm_ready ]
```

checks that there isn't any file or directory or symbolic link exists by the name `.wm_ready` in `tmp` folder

Comment: Or named pipe, or character or block device, or socket, or symbolic link. Basically it checks for the existence of a directory entry with the specified name.

Answer (score 6):

It is to check that the FILE exists. You can refer the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) for details.

```
-e FILE
    FILE exists
```

On a side note here are some other useful options

```
   -d FILE
          FILE exists and is a directory
   -e FILE
          FILE exists
   -f FILE
          FILE exists and is a regular file
   -h FILE
          FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -L)
   -r FILE
          FILE exists and is readable
   -s FILE
          FILE exists and has a size greater than zero
   -w FILE
          FILE exists and is writable
   -x FILE
          FILE exists and is executable
   -z STRING
          the length of STRING is zero
```

Answer (score 1):

See the manual for your shell. In mine (*ksh93* on Mac OS X 10.10.3), it says:

```
-e file
   True, if file exists.
```